# Fatal error: Class 'Mfn_Tag_Cloud_Widget' not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I had an existing WordPress website which was working great. Suddenly, I couldn't log in to my Admin Panel, I found this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mfn_Tag_Cloud_Widget' not found in /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 106
```

*I used a WP Plugin to extract a backup and restore it on a fresh WP installation, but I got the same error.*

Any help!?

The full error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mfn_Tag_Cloud_Widget' not found in ..\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php:106 Stack trace: #0 ..\wp-includes\widgets.php(113): WP_Widget_Factory->register('Mfn_Tag_Cloud_W...') #1 ..\wp-content\themes\MyTheme\functions\widget-functions.php(21): register_widget('Mfn_Tag_Cloud_W...') #2 ..\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): mfn_register_widget('') #3 ..\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #4 ..\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 ..\wp-includes\widgets.php(1474): do_action('widgets_init') #6 ..\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): wp_widgets_init('') #7 ..\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #8 ..\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #9 ..\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 106
```

Comment: Download the `Muffin Tag Cloud` plugin and upload the folder into `wp-content/plugins` directory. Does it change something?

Comment: @TahaPaksu Do you mean `Custom Tag Cloud` plugin? because when I searched for `Muffin Tag Cloud` I find the previous one.

Comment: Maybe I don't know, but when I've searched this class, I found that it's related to Muffin Tag Cloud. Maybe Custom Tag Cloud plugin has this class.

Comment: @TahaPaksu I downloaded `Custom Tag Cloud` and paste its folder into `wp-content/plugins` directory and the error message still the same.
Thanks for your help and please if you have another solution, please let me know!

Comment: Change the wp-class-widget-factory.php contents with https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php

Comment: or directly update/reinstall the wordpress all together.

Comment: @TahaPaksu That's what I did before. I used a fresh WP installation and all these files has been restored to its default.
I have also copy/paste the `class-wp-widget-factory.php` content with the updated one 4.4.0.